# How to change border of a picture in a list using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying make an image get a border when the mouse is over it. However, because the pictures are in a list, when the mouse is over the image, the whole list item gets the specific border, not just the image. The CSS is as follows:

```
#myImgDesign:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  transform-origin: 25% 50%;
  transform: scale(1.095, 1.095);
  border-style: dotted
}
```

Here's a jsfiddle explaining it much better than I can:

https://jsfiddle.net/jr2zmpms/6/

I'd like to have the border set only on the image, not on the whole list item. How is this possible to do using CSS? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Put img in the selector?

Comment: please let us know what worked for you and consider accepting answer if any of them worked

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] in the question itself, not on a third-party site.

Answer (score 0):

```
#myImgDesign:hover img {
  opacity: 0.8;
  transform-origin: 25% 50%;
  transform: scale(1.095, 1.095);
 border-style: dotted;
 }
```

This will do it.

you select img tag inside on hover and then add border there.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you're selecting the parent - you need to have the `<img>` selected itself:

```
#myImgDesign>img:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  transform-origin: 25% 50%;
  transform: scale(1.095, 1.095);
  border-style: dotted
}
```

Also, `id`'s are supposed to be unique. Make sure `myImgDesign` is a class and not used the way you demonstrated your problem in your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
#myImgDesign img:hover  {
  opacity: 0.8;
  transform-origin: 25% 50%;
  transform: scale(1.095, 1.095);
  border-style: dotted;
}
```

Hope this helps

```css
#myImgDesign img:hover {
  opacity: 0.8;
  transform-origin: 25% 50%;
  transform: scale(1.095, 1.095);
  border-style: dotted;
}

ul.nobullet {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="row-img nobullet">
  <li id="myImgDesign"><img style="width:100px; height:100px;" src="ruhaszinek/black.jpg"></li>
  <li id="myImgDesign"><img style="width:100px; height:100px;" src="ruhaszinek/blue.jpg"></li>
  <li id="myImgDesign"><img style="width:100px; height:100px;" src="ruhaszinek/green.jpg"></li>
  <li id="myImgDesign"><img style="width:100px; height:100px;" src="ruhaszinek/orange.jpg"></li>
  <li id="myImgDesign"><img style="width:100px; height:100px;" src="ruhaszinek/red.jpg"></li>
  <li id="myImgDesign"><img style="width:100px; height:100px;" src="ruhaszinek/yellow.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

do the
 #myImgDesign img:hover {blablabla}

Answer (score 0):

You can add this...

```
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope can i help you. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.gallerycontainer{
position: relative;
/*Add a height attribute and set to largest image's height to prevent overlaying*/
}

.thumbnail img{
border: 1px solid white;
margin: 0 5px 5px 0;
width:80px;
height:80px;
}

.thumbnail:hover{
background-color: transparent;
}

.thumbnail:hover img{
border: 1px solid blue;
}

.thumbnail span{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
position: absolute;
background-color: lightyellow;
padding: 5px;
left: -1000px;
border: 1px dashed gray;
visibility: hidden;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}

.thumbnail span img{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
border-width: 0;
padding: 2px;
}

.thumbnail:hover span{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
visibility: visible;
top: 0;
left: 230px; /*position where enlarged image should offset horizontally */
z-index: 50;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallerycontainer">

<a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb">Ship 1<span><img src="http://www.gettyimages.ca/gi-resources/images/Homepage/Hero/UK/CMS_Creative_164657191_Kingfisher.jpg" /></span></a>

<br />

<a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb">Ship 2<span><img src="https://wallpapers.pub/web/wallpapers/birds-water-spray-wallpaper/3840x2160.jpg" /></span></a>

</div>
```